# A multi-armed bandit problem in clinical trial

Tags: clinical-trials, multiarmed-bandit

Suppose that we have two drugs A and B with levels $i=1,\ldots,I$ and $j = 1, \ldots, J$, respectively. These two different drugs are given to patients in a clinical trial. $p_{ij}$ is the prior dose limiting toxicity probability from the dose combination of $i$ and $j$. Let $\theta$ be the target probability of dose limiting toxicity. Patients are assigned to doses adaptively where the toxicity status of previously enrolled patients are used to determine the dose level for the next cohort of patients.

The objective is to find the dose that minimizes $\mathbb{E}[l(\pi_{ij}, \theta) | X]$ where $l$ is a loss function, $\pi_{ij}$ is the posterior probability of toxicity and $X$ is the patients' toxicity data. We start from the minimum dose and assign some patients to it. Then, we observe the toxicity of patients and calculate the loss function for all the doses and choose the next dose for patient assignment that minimizes $\mathbb{E}[l(\pi_{ij}, \theta)| X]$ and so on. Let $n_{ij}$ be the number of the patients on dose combination $(i,j)$. The problem is that, when we assign patients to a dose, it  will usually have a smaller expected loss due to smaller variance of posterior and it tends to not explore other doses that still has no patients assigned to them. How should I modify my expected loss to handle this? I know this is a multi-armed bandit problem. But I'm not much familiar with it.